# Header size problems

Tags: css, wordpress, header, styles, size

I'm developing a WordPress website and have some trouble with the header width on some specific screens as you can see in the image below.

Does anybody know where I can adjust this in my template? (I guess it has something to do with the min-width.) To take a deeper look, the URL is [www.brainfarts.shop](http://www.brainfarts.shop).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an error with the media queries, I see the trouble when I change the width between 1,000px and 1,280px (both widths included).

I don't know much about Wordpress but if I were you I would try to mess with the site changing things with the element inspector of any browser and then try to apply the changes in some place in your Wordpress, in some section where you can insert your code (css).

Comment: See my answer  below for details